# Why it is possible to write currying?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have the following code:

```
object ContraCats {

  val showString = Show[String]

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val m = showString.contramap[Symbol](_.name).show('dave)
    val a = showString.contramap[Symbol](_.name)('dave)

  }
}
```

As you can see, it is possible to write as currying version and the other as method call. Why it is possible?

Comment: Could you please add all imports that you are using? My `cats` 1.0.1 gives me "error: cats.Show[Symbol] does not take parameters", because `Show` doesn't seem to have an `apply` method.

Comment: ...and could you please also add the information about the specific version you are using? Not only does it not compile in 1.0.1, but I also couldn't find any version in which it does compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `contramap` returns a `Show` instance.

`Show` has both the `show` and the `apply` methods.

The `apply` method is special in Scala, since this two are equivalent:

```
someValue.apply(someArg)
someValue(someArg)
```

So in your example what's happening is that you're calling the `apply` method on the `Show` instance returned by `contramap`, i.e.

```
val m = showString.contramap[Symbol](_.name).show('dave)
val a = showString.contramap[Symbol](_.name).apply('dave)
```

#### Update

While the explanation above would make sense, I realized cats's `Show` doesn't have an `apply` method, so your code shouldn't compile (I tried on a REPL and it doesn't)

Comment: Why `a` has type string not `Show[Symbol]`? Looking at the `def apply[A](implicit instance: Show[A]): Show[A] = instance` return a `Show[A]` instance not a string.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella But [Show](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Show.html) doesn't seem to have an `apply` method?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin it doesn't now. It used to have it in previous versions of cats (which is likely what the OP is using)

Comment: @zero_coding you're looking at the `apply` method on the `Show` companion object, which is not the `apply` method on the instance. The most recent version of cats doesn't even have the `apply` method on the instance, so your code probably doesn't compile under cats 1.0

Comment: @GabrielePetronella That explains it, thank you Sir! It's a bit difficult to tell, because it *might* import some implicit from somewhere, which wraps the `Show[Symbol]` into some kind of `ShowOps[Symbol](wrapped: Show[Symbol]) { def apply(s: Symbol): String = wrapped.show(s) }` - thingie. Since OP omitted all the imports, I couldn't exclude that possibility.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Hm, sorry, I'm still not quite content with the explanation. I haven't properly bisected `cats` history, but a brief scan of the commits between 2015 and 2017 didn't reveal any versions in which `Show` had an `apply`? Could you name a specific version in which this is supposed to work without additional implicit conversions?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin The show has an apply method https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Show.scala.

Comment: @zero_coding I mean the trait, not the companion object. I assumed that it is obvious from the context.